# Mining on Ropsten/Testnet - Not Working Post Hard Fork

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, testnets, hardforks

Ever since the ropsten hard fork and upgrading to geth 1.7.0, I am unable to mine for test ether.

```
Geth
Version: 1.7.0-stable
```

Before the hard fork, I could manage to mine a few blocks each day.  Post hard fork, haven't been able to mine a single block.
Is there a new setting or config required on geth?

Comment: Same problem with my geth node v1.7.0. Transactions aren't working very well either. Some of them take hours to be mined or verified on etherscan.

Comment: @JuanIgnacioPérezSacristán yeah, definitely they're linked. I've noticed inconsistent transaction mining times also.  If I'm not able to mine, then other people can't either. So just total pool of computers able to process transactions has gone down.

Comment: It was mentioned a couple of days ago in https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/72dnmn/i_have_a_lot_of_pending_transaction_on_ropsten_am/ about someone mining only empty blocks.

Comment: @Ismael Got it, thanks: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf4d8e706cfb25c0decbbdd4d2e2cc10c66376a3f#mine

Answer (score 1):

As @Ismael (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/2124/ismael) pointed out, some miner is blocking the network:
[Miner blocking the network](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf4d8e706cfb25c0decbbdd4d2e2cc10c66376a3f#mine)